# How to get the real path of My Documents

Tags: c#

Commonly, we can use this method to get the path of My Documents:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

but, if My Documents was redirect to another location, how to get the real path?

Comment: That should work in all circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the entire point of `Environment.GetFolderPath`, if the folder was redirected it will point at the redirected location.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( not tested ), even though, what you posted should always work no matter what but just for the sake of giving you another option:

```
[DllImport("shfolder.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern int SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, int nFolder,
IntPtr hToken, int dwFlags, System.Text.StringBuilder lpszPath);
[STAThread]

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(260);
     SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, 5, IntPtr.Zero, 0, path);
     Console.WriteLine(path);
     Console.Read();
}
```